# Why are text/buttons jumping around on page load (Chrome)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

Please visit our homepage at http://froy.com.

Within the first half second the page loads, you see the "Shop" buttons along with the text that go above the buttons appear near the left side of your screen. When the page finishes loading, they move to their proper position.

This issue appears to only happen on Chrome. Our website is responsive.

Ideally, we want the site to load just like http://ae.com. They use a similar layout with their homepage text and buttons, yet they all load properly.

I don't mind the video loading last and everything shifting lower when the video appears, but I find it very unprofessional for the text/buttons to shift left to right.

Answer (score 0):

Those buttons shouldn't be a problem, they are in what position they would be if the video didn't render.
As soon as it renders, they should be fine.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I wish that was the case, but I don't think so - I can recognize the text/button that is supposed to be horizontally centered appearing at the left then shifting right to its appropriate position.

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at your video and video container. Maybe try changing the `.slideshow-video-container` CSS Rule to this:

```
.slideshow-video-container {
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 25px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Tried it, but the issue persists.

Comment: Did anything change? The issue is that video container isn't taking up any space until the video loads. This normally isn't an issue when I do video because the mobile fallback image account for the space, but I don't see any type of image for mobile fallback.

Comment: No visible changes. The video actually does have a fallback, but I'm not sure if it appears before the video since everything loads so quickly.

Comment: Where is the `<img>` fallback? I don't see it.

Comment: The video tag uses a poster attribute, which is the image that is displayed while the video is downloading. The video loads too quickly to really notice.

Comment: I normally use a separate `<img>` in the same container as the video. Then hide depending on width. That way you don't just have a big play button in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you hide the entire page with an overlay element and only after everything is loaded, fade that element out. This should solve most or all of your render issues. Here's an example:

```js
$(function(){
  $('#overlay').fadeOut();
})
```

```css
div#content{
  width:50%;
  margin:auto;
  p{
    margin:2rem;
    padding:0;
  }
}

div#overlay{
  position:fixed;
  top:0;left:0;right:0;bottom:0;
  background:#fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id=content>
  <p>Authoritatively build effective networks rather than transparent ideas. Monotonectally pontificate high-quality content whereas world-class schemas. Distinctively leverage other's distributed scenarios vis-a-vis synergistic applications. Proactively implement bricks-and-clicks.</p>
  <p>Authoritatively build effective networks rather than transparent ideas. Monotonectally pontificate high-quality content whereas world-class schemas. Distinctively leverage other's distributed scenarios vis-a-vis synergistic applications. Proactively implement bricks-and-clicks.</p>
  <p>Authoritatively build effective networks rather than transparent ideas. Monotonectally pontificate high-quality content whereas world-class schemas. Distinctively leverage other's distributed scenarios vis-a-vis synergistic applications. Proactively implement bricks-and-clicks.</p>
  <p>Authoritatively build effective networks rather than transparent ideas. Monotonectally pontificate high-quality content whereas world-class schemas. Distinctively leverage other's distributed scenarios vis-a-vis synergistic applications. Proactively implement bricks-and-clicks.</p>
  <p>Authoritatively build effective networks rather than transparent ideas. Monotonectally pontificate high-quality content whereas world-class schemas. Distinctively leverage other's distributed scenarios vis-a-vis synergistic applications. Proactively implement bricks-and-clicks.</p>
  <p>Authoritatively build effective networks rather than transparent ideas. Monotonectally pontificate high-quality content whereas world-class schemas. Distinctively leverage other's distributed scenarios vis-a-vis synergistic applications. Proactively implement bricks-and-clicks.</p>
  <p>Authoritatively build effective networks rather than transparent ideas. Monotonectally pontificate high-quality content whereas world-class schemas. Distinctively leverage other's distributed scenarios vis-a-vis synergistic applications. Proactively implement bricks-and-clicks.</p>
  <p>Authoritatively build effective networks rather than transparent ideas. Monotonectally pontificate high-quality content whereas world-class schemas. Distinctively leverage other's distributed scenarios vis-a-vis synergistic applications. Proactively implement bricks-and-clicks.</p>
  <p>Authoritatively build effective networks rather than transparent ideas. Monotonectally pontificate high-quality content whereas world-class schemas. Distinctively leverage other's distributed scenarios vis-a-vis synergistic applications. Proactively implement bricks-and-clicks.</p>
  <p>Authoritatively build effective networks rather than transparent ideas. Monotonectally pontificate high-quality content whereas world-class schemas. Distinctively leverage other's distributed scenarios vis-a-vis synergistic applications. Proactively implement bricks-and-clicks.</p>
  <p>Authoritatively build effective networks rather than transparent ideas. Monotonectally pontificate high-quality content whereas world-class schemas. Distinctively leverage other's distributed scenarios vis-a-vis synergistic applications. Proactively implement bricks-and-clicks.</p>
  <p>Authoritatively build effective networks rather than transparent ideas. Monotonectally pontificate high-quality content whereas world-class schemas. Distinctively leverage other's distributed scenarios vis-a-vis synergistic applications. Proactively implement bricks-and-clicks.</p>
</div>

<div id=overlay></div>
```